# How to run the firebase emulator with a specific host address?

Tags: flutter, firebase-tools

I'm trying to connect my flutter app running on a physical device with the firebase emulator on the local machine, followed these steps in this [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161387/firebase-firestore-emulator-on-physical-ios-android-device) to do so, but when running this command

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --export-on-exit ./test_data/ --import ./test_data/
```

with this configuration in `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

it results in this output:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, storage
⚠  functions: You are running the functions emulator in debug mode (port=9229). This means that functions will execute in sequence rather than in parallel.
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, hosting, pubsub
✔  functions: Using node@14 from local cache.
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
⚠  firestore: Port 8080 is not open on 0.0.0.0, could not start Firestore Emulator.
⚠  firestore: To select a different host/port, specify that host/port in a firebase.json config file:
      {
        // ...
        "emulators": {
          "firestore": {
            "host": "HOST",
            "port": "PORT"
          }
        }
      }
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
```

and this error:

> Error: Could not start Firestore Emulator, port taken.

#### Obvious solution

Kill whatever app using the port 8080, more likely it is the firestore emulator of the pervious session, from this [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67622395/9957168). After killing the app and running the command again, the same error occurs.

#### Note

even using my machine address in the local network instead of `0.0.0.0` did not work and results in the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use another port, like `8000`, instead of `8080` for firestor entry in `firebase.json` so the command could run.

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --export-on-exit ./test_data/ --import ./test_data/
```

Taken from this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1740). Also, using `0.0.0.0` will make firebase emulator use localhost or the ip address of the machine in the local network.

Although `lsof -i :8080` doesn’t return any result indicating there is an application using the port `8080`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing the: `"host": "0.0.0.0",` from firestore.json. [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration)

This command helped me kill the app running on port 8080:

`lsof -ti tcp:8080 | xargs kill`

Comment: i did kill the app that was using the port, but the error persists.  also, removing the `"host": "0.0.0.0"` will default it to localhost i believe which means it will not work when running the app on a physical device.